# Multilevel binding with d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to implement 'multilevel' binding with d3 library. I have a set of objects (Manager) where each object contains it's own set of items (Employees). Result page must contain an element for each Manager. Manager element also must contain one element per each Employee listed in source object.
I was able to build initial layout. But on update it seems that d3 can't find matches between existing elements changed data. It just adds duplicating employees.

Here's a fiddle with my sample code
http://jsfiddle.net/02bptmd6/

```
var initialData = [
    {k:1, v:150, items: [{k:1, v:1}, {k:2, v:2}, {k:3, v:3}]},
    {k:2, v:100, items: [{k:4, v:4}, {k:5, v:5}]},
    {k:3, v:150, items: [{k:6, v:6}, {k:7, v:7}, {k:8, v:8}]},
    {k:4, v:60, items: [{k:9, v:9}]},
    {k:5, v:200, items: [{k:10, v:10}, {k:11, v:11}, {k:12, v:12}, {k:13, v:13}]}];

function updateChart(data){
    var bars = d3.select('#container').selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data, function(d) {return d.k;});

    bars.enter()
        .append('div')
        .classed('bar', true);

    bars.transition(1000)
        .style('width', function(d) {return d.v + 'px';});

    bars.exit().transition(1000)
        .style('width', function(d) {return '0px';})
        .style('height', function(d) {return '0px';})
        .remove();

    var items = bars.selectAll('.items')
        .data(function(d) {return d.items;}, function(d){return d.k;});
    items
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .classed('item', true)
        .append('span')
        .text(function(d) {return d.v});
    items.exit()
        .classed('item_exit', true)        
        .remove();
}

function changeData(){
    var data = [
        {k:1, v:150, items: [{k:1, v:1}, {k:2, v:2}]},
        {k:4, v:150, items: [{k:9, v:9}, {k:14, v:14}, {k:15, v:15}]},
        {k:5, v:200, items: [{k:10, v:10}, {k:11, v:11}, {k:12, v:12}]}];

    updateChart(data);
}

updateChart(initialData);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found an error. I'm using 'item' class for 'Employees' but used to select them by '.items' selector.